# Swagger/NSwag: Redefine Parameter Type

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, nswag

We are using swagger / nswag for documentation of a webapi project.

As BodyParameters for the ActionMethods we use classes with the suffix Command, that contain parameters for e.g. creating a Domain-Object persisted in a database.

A Command-Class could look like this:

```
public class CreateChildCommand {
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
}
```

While Position is a simple int, Parent is a Domain-Class persisted in a database. May it look somehow like this:

```
public class Parent {

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

It can be loaded from database by its Id, so we just pass the id as parameter in the Json for the Command-Parameter like this:

```
{
    "Position": 3,
    "Parent": "41E71207-7F1E-4895-8BCC-14E1293A7907"
}
```

When deserializing the Json the parent gets loaded by its Id via a Dao. 
The problem now is, that swagger/nswag doesn't understand that "magic" and displays the parameters for the method like this:

```
{
    "Position": number,
    "Parent": {
         Id: "Guid",
         "Name": "string",
         ...
    }
}
```

Is there any way to tell swagger to replace the Type for parent to make it look like this:

```
{
    "Position": "int",
    "Parent": "Guid"
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [JsonSchemaAttribute](https://github.com/RSuter/NJsonSchema/blob/master/src/NJsonSchema/Annotations/JsonSchemaAttribute.cs) attribute to override the schema type of a complex property:

```
public class CreateChildCommand {
    [JsonSchema(JsonObjectType.String, Format = "guid")]
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }

    public int Position { get; set; }
}
```

The attribute is implemented in the NJsonSchema library: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NJsonSchema/

Another option is to use a type mapper to map all Parent classes to a string, see https://github.com/RSuter/NJsonSchema/wiki/Type-Mappers

Comment: I did it via TypeMappers:

Comment: The `JsonSchemaAttribute` doesn't seem to work in this way on the current version of Swashbuckle. There is no effect on the generated schema.

Comment: This only works when generating the spec with nswag/njs but not with swashbuckle